# Radio streaming lost after delete Pulse Audio

Tags: sound, streaming

I was badly advised and I uninstalled Pulse Audio. I lost all sound on my 18.04 PC

After some effort I reinstalled following the [Ubuntu Sound Troubleshooting site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure).

However now I can no longer stream radio through Odio or Shortwave. I can in my browser but neither app will play. Odio gives no feedback, but Shortwave gives the status message:

> Failed to connect: connection refused.

Any Ideas where I can go from here?

Answer (score 0):

This now works

I *think* it came back after I did

```
pulseaudio -k
pulseaudio --start
```

Based on [this page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Muted_application)

I'm not sure, because I left it for 12 hours before it finally came back